# Bypass invalid SSL certificate errors .Net / c#

Tags: c#, ssl

I've got a development system which I'm trying to get to communicate to a third-party secure web service.

The third party have provided me with a certificate which I've imported locally. I've made sure the certificate is added to the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' store. It seems to have imported correctly, as if I go Chrome and try to access one of the service urls mentioned in the web service WSDL file I firstly get a popup asking to me to confirm which certificate to use (there's only the one option) and it then lets me through. However, if I then use the same WSDL file to create a service reference in Visual Studio, and make a call to one of the services in my code, I get an error saying 'Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority'.

Ideally I would get VS to acknowledge the cert when I'm making the webservice call, but seeing as this is a development system I'm also happy to ignore the SSL errors for the time being.

To this end I've added the following to my code, along with variations on the protocols I'm specifying (e.g. only specifying SSL3, taking out SSL3 etc):

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

But no matter what I do I still get the SSL error when I try to make the service call.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get VS to accept the certificate is present (as Chrome seems to do) or, alternatively, how to get the code to ignore the SSL error for now, so I can proceed with development, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use this certificate to authenticate with the third party service?

Comment: You have to get past the pop up once with the service.  What account is used when you run the service?  Do you have the service to run as Admin?  Then have Admin run application once so certificate get stored as an Admin Trusted Root Certification and not a user path in the registry.

Comment: @Adriani6 The certificate is installed on my local cert store, and when I try to access the third party service using Chrome I get asked to choose a certificate to connect with (with the relevant cert being the only option available). Once I choose that cert I am able to access the service in Chrome. However, the cert doesn't seem to be being used when I make a service call from VS.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I understand - the service is a third party one, it's run on an external server which I have no access to. I have tried running Chrome as both a normal user and as admin, and likewise with VS which I'm using to debug the application I'm writing, but in all cases I still get an SSL exception when making a call to the web service from VS.

Comment: You said "SSL error when I try to make the service call".  You have a Web Server on a remote machine, but you can also have a SERVICE running locally that makes the connection to the remote machine.  I assumed the service call was the local service.  the correct way of debugging the issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture the good connection using Chrome.  Then compare the http headers in the initial request from Chrome with you application.  Make you application headers look exactly like the Chrome headers.

Comment: @jdweng Ah, I see - no, the service is running on the remote machine. I then have a local application, which I'm debugging in VS and which makes calls to the service that is running on the remote machine, and it's those calls that are returning an SSL error. I'll try comparing the http headers and see if that throws up anything obvious.